# 'word' not in Vocabulary in a corpus with words shown in a single list only in gensim library

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, gensim, word2vec, nltk-book

Hello Community Members,

At present, I am implementing the Word2Vec algorithm.

Firstly, I have extracted the data (sentences), break and split the sentences into tokens (words), remove the punctuation marks and store the tokens in a single list. The list basically contain the words. Then I have calculated the frequency of words and then computed it occurrences in terms of frequency. It results a list.

Next, I am trying to load the model using gensim. However, I am facing a problem. The problem is about `the word is not in the vocabulary`. The code snippet, whatever I have tried is as follows.

```
import nltk, re, gensim
import string
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg, stopwords

def preprocessing():
    raw_data = (gutenberg.raw('shakespeare-hamlet.txt'))
    tokens = word_tokenize(raw_data)
    tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    global words
    words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
    sw = (stopwords.words('english'))
    sw1= (['.', ',', '"', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}'])
    sw2= (['for', 'on', 'ed', 'es', 'ing', 'of', 'd', 'is', 'has', 'have', 'been', 'had', 'was', 'are', 'were', 'a', 'an', 'the', 't', 's', 'than', 'that', 'it', '&', 'and', 'where', 'there', 'he', 'she', 'i', 'and', 'with', 'it', 'to', 'shall', 'why', 'ham'])
    stop=sw+sw1+sw2
    words = [w for w in words if not w in stop]
preprocessing()

def freq_count():
    fd = nltk.FreqDist(words)
    print(fd.most_common())
    freq_count()
def word_embedding():
    for i in range(len(words)):
        model = Word2Vec(words, size = 100, sg = 1, window = 3, min_count = 1, iter = 10, workers = 4)
        model.init_sims(replace = True)
        model.save('word2vec_model')
        model = Word2Vec.load('word2vec_model')
        similarities = model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')
        for word, score in similarities:
            print(word , score)
word_embedding()
```

Note: I am using Python 3.7 in Windows OS. From the `syntax of gensim`, it is suggested to use sentences and split into tokens and apply the same to build and train the model. My question is that how to apply the same to a corpus with single list containing only words. I have specified the words also using list, i.e. [words], during the training of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter passed to `Word2Vec` expects an list of sentences. You're passing a list of words

```
import nltk
import re
import gensim
import string
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg, stopwords


def preprocessing():
    raw_data = (gutenberg.raw('shakespeare-hamlet.txt'))
    tokens = word_tokenize(raw_data)
    tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    global words
    words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
    sw = (stopwords.words('english'))
    sw1 = (['.', ',', '"', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}'])
    sw2 = (['for', 'on', 'ed', 'es', 'ing', 'of', 'd', 'is', 'has', 'have', 'been', 'had', 'was', 'are', 'were', 'a', 'an', 'the', 't',
            's', 'than', 'that', 'it', '&', 'and', 'where', 'there', 'he', 'she', 'i', 'and', 'with', 'it', 'to', 'shall', 'why', 'ham'])
    stop = sw + sw1 + sw2
    words = [w for w in words if not w in stop]


preprocessing()


def freq_count():
    fd = nltk.FreqDist(words)
    print(fd.most_common())
    freq_count()


def word_embedding():
    for i in range(len(words)):
        print(type(words))
        #pass words as a list.
        model = Word2Vec([words], size=100, sg=1, window=3,
                        min_count=1, iter=10, workers=4)
        model.init_sims(replace=True)
        model.save('word2vec_model')
        model = Word2Vec.load('word2vec_model')
        similarities = model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')
        for word, score in similarities:
            print(word, score)


word_embedding()
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Madhan. From the syntax's, I learned that the input to the w2v model, is facilitated by sentences (list of list of sentences), where each and every sentence is splitted into token of words. I am just interested to know instead of lists of list of splitted words, does the model accepts only a `single list` comprising the token of words of all the sentences.

Answer (score 2):

[Madhan Varadhodiyil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51947552/130288) has identified your main problem, passing a list-of-words where `Word2Vec` expects a sequence-of-sentences (such as a list-of-list-of-words). As a result, each word is seen as a sentence, and then each letter is seen as one word of a sentence – and your resulting model thus probably has just a few dozen single-character 'words'.

If you enabled logging at the INFO level, and watched the output – always good ideas when trying to understand a process or debug a problem – you may have noticed the reported counts of sentences/words as being off.

Additionally:

- 'Hamlet' has about 30,000 words – but gensim `Word2Vec`'s optimized code has an implementation limit of 10,000 words per text example (sentence) – so passing the full text in as if it were a single text will cause about 2/3 of it to be silently ignored. Pass it as a series of shorter texts (such as sentences, paragraphs, or even scenes/acts) instead.
- 30,000 words is very, very, very small for good word-vectors, which are typically based on millions to billions of words' worth of usage examples. When working with a small corpus, sometimes more training passes than the default `epochs=5` can help, sometimes shrinking the dimensionality of the vectors below the default `vector_size=100` can help, but you won't be getting the full value of the algorithm, which really depends on large diverse text examples to achieve meaningful arrangements of words.
- Usually words with just 1 or a few usage examples can't get good vectors from those few (not-necessarily-representative) examples, and further the large number of such words act as noise/interference in the training of other words (that *could* get good word-vectors). So setting `min_count=1` usually results in *worse* word-vectors, for both rare and frequent words, on task-specific measures of quality, than the default of discarding rare words entirely.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo for the suggestion. Could you please suggest what will be ideal parameter values of the w2v model. I mean what will be the ideal values of the main parameter of the w2v model, i.e. `min_count, size, workers and window` size for small and large size corpus.

Comment: There's no universal ideal: you have to try it with your data, & whatever your particular end goal is, then adjust based on some hopefully-objective and repeatable way of scoring results. (I'm not sure what your end goal may be in training on a single Shakespeare work.) Usually it's good to start with the defaults, then tinker – but if you do have a rigorous repeatable quantitative way to score your model, you can do a larger automatic exploration of possible parameter combinations. You'll usually get fastest training with `workers` somewhere between 3 and the number of CPU cores.

Comment: The best `window` may vary based on your end-goal, but can perhaps trend smaller with larger corpuses to save time while still getting "good" vectors. The supportable `size` will be smaller with smaller corpuses, and larger with larger corpuses. Often it is necessary to increase `min_count`, discarding more low-frequency words, in larger corpuses just to help keep the model size-on-RAM manageable – but that will often improve the quality of the remaining word-vectors, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern @gojomo.